# List items not being passed to the view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, entity-framework, .net-core

For my small web app project I've created a model called Company that includes basic company info & also a list of sales reps from different business partners. This is my Contact Model:

```
 public class Company
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Promo { get; set; } // Yes or No field
        public List<Contact> Contacts { get; set; }
        public class Contact
        {
            [Key]
            public int ContactID { get; set; }
            public int CompanyID { get; set; }
            public string ContactName { get; set; }
            public string ContactNumber { get; set; }
        }
    }
```

This is how I pass the data into my local database:

```
var companiesData = new Company[]
        {
            new Company
            {
             Name = "Some name", Promo="Y", Contacts = new List<Contact> { new Contact {ContactName="John Doe", ContactNumber="(828)292-2912", CompanyID=1}, 
           }}, // ... some more contacts
        };
        foreach (Company c in companiesData)
        {
            context.Companies.Add(c);
        }
        context.SaveChanges();
```

**How do I load the contact list items onto the razor view?** I'm looking at my database and it's showing a blank field for "Contacts". The rest of the data shows up just fine.

Comment: Your saving doesn't look right, `context.Companies.Add(c)` should be `context.Contacts.Add(c)`. And you need to save your new `Company` first so you have a `CompanyID` to save with the contact

Comment: `Contacts` property is a `List<Contact>` so it's not mapped to a field but rather to a foreign key in `Contacts` table that matches  `ID` of the `Company`. Where do you see it as "blank field"?

Comment: In the dbo.Companies table from the SQL Object Explorer. The column Contacts is blank while the rest has data (passed from the same object)

Comment: Make sure when you are accessing the Companies Db Set - that you are using `Include`, such as `context.Companies.Include(p => p.Contacts).ToArray()`, then send that to the View as the model. If this resolves the issue then I can post this as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So based on your description, it sounds like you are receiving the model - but the Contacts collection is null or empty.

This is because EntityFrameworkCore needs child sets to be included explicitly using `Include` on your context Db Set. [See here for more information](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data)

The code below is an example of how to include child collections in your model with eager loading

```
public class CompanyController : Controller
{
    // This import is needed for using the 'Include' method.
    using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

    private ApplicationDbContext _context;
    public CompanyController(ApplicationDbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }
    // GET: /<controller>/
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        List<Company> viewModelData = _context.Companies.Include(p => p.Contacts).ToList();

        return View(viewModelData);
    }
}

public class Company
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Promo { get; set; } // Yes or No field
    public List<Contact> Contacts { get; set; }
    public class Contact
    {
        [Key]
        public int ContactID { get; set; }
        public int CompanyID { get; set; }
        public string ContactName { get; set; }
        public string ContactNumber { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And your Database Context

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);
        // Customize the ASP.NET Identity model and override the defaults if needed.
        // For example, you can rename the ASP.NET Identity table names and more.
        // Add your customizations after calling base.OnModelCreating(builder);
    }

    public DbSet<Company> Companies { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Contact> Contacts { get; set; }
}
```

View file should set the model like so

```
@model List<Company>

<h3>Do something with 'Model' here</h3>
```

Comment: Please mark it as the answer when necessary, glad it worked.

Comment: Anything reading data will have to use the `Include`, Creating data should be okay because you're inserting into the collection and saving. Updating and Deleting may need an `Include` depending on how you're deleting the data.

Comment: For the Edit Post method, how do I modify this so that update the contacts? My code now only allows me to update company info.

Comment: You will have to `Include` the Contacts, and then iterate through the contacts to update the values, or get by id via a LINQ method such as `FirstOrDefault`, when you've finished then call `Update` on the context Db Set, and then `SaveChangesAsync`

Comment: Can you answer my question here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43644490/allow-user-to-edit-list-items-in-mvc

Comment: I'm having trouble modifying the CREATE method. I left the GET method unchanged & used Include in POST. I also added forms for inputting contact info in the Create view. I've tested the form. My input for Company shows up on the view but not for Contact. Note: I used @Model.Contacts to pass the list entity into my razor view (ex. <label asp-for="@Model.Contacts".... Any hint?

Comment: The Label will only display something like `System.Collections.Generic.List'1[Contact]` which is the default behavior of ToString that returns type name of your collection, you'll have to loop through the Contacts and create a label for each. You'll also have to `Include` the Contacts collection in your GET context query.

Comment: I did try to use a for loop (@for(var rep = 0; rep < Model.Contacts.Count(); ++rep) -- but it returned an error message saying "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Comment: `Model.Contacts` is possibly null, ensure it is Included in your GET method, and that the model is being passed with populated data.

Answer (score 2):

see https://dotnetfiddle.net/xb3g68

entities:

```
public class Company
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Promo { get; set; } 
    public virtual List<Contact> Contacts { get; set; }       
}

public class Contact
{
    [Key]
    public int ContactID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("Company")]
    public int CompanyID { get; set; }
    public virtual Company Company { get; set; }
    public string ContactName { get; set; }
    public string ContactNumber { get; set; }
}
```

test harness:

```
public static void Main()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Hello World");
    FakeDbContext context = new FakeDbContext();
    var companiesData = new Company[]
    {
        new Company
        {
            Name = "Some name", Promo="Y", Contacts = new List<Contact> { new Contact {ContactName="John Doe", ContactNumber="(828)292-2912", CompanyID=1}},
        },
        new Company
        {
            Name = "Another name", Promo="N",  Contacts = new List<Contact> { new Contact {ContactName="Jane Doe", ContactNumber="(828)292-2912", CompanyID=2}},
        },
    };
    foreach (Company c in companiesData)
    {
        context.Companies.Add(c);
        foreach (Contact contact in c.Contacts)
        {
            context.Contacts.Add(contact);  
        }
    }
    context.SaveChanges();
    Console.WriteLine("Save done.");
    var companies = context.Companies.ToList();
    Console.WriteLine("companies.Count: " + companies.Count);
    for (int i = 0; i < companies.Count; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("company[{0}].Name: {1}", i,     companies[i].Name));
        for (int j = 0; j < companies[i].Contacts.Count; j++)
        {               
Console.WriteLine(string.Format("company[{0}].Contacts[{1}].ContactName: {2}", i, j, companies[i].Contacts[j].ContactName));
        }
    }
    Console.WriteLine("Bye World");
}
```

output:

*Hello World*

*Save done.*

*companies.Count: 2*

*company[0].Name: Some name*

*company[0].Contacts[0].ContactName: John Doe*

*company[1].Name: Another name*

*company[1].Contacts[0].ContactName: Jane Doe*

*Bye World*

Comment: do you have the data saving to your db fine now - so contacts etc with the companyid reference set?

Comment: just be careful with ID values - with a proper EF provider against a database you'll probably want `[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]` set below your `[Key]` attribute, and EF will create the ID value on context add. You'd then use that for the foreign key. Note that the db won't update until `SaveChanges` is called. The comment above about using `.Include()` is spot on as well. If you're using .NET Core, have a play with a SQLite InMemory tutorial project - I tried getting dotnetfiddle to run the .NET.4.5 versions of SQLite and Effort without a result

Answer (score 2):

Hi on my final project i did the same with viewmodel because is data from two different tables and give more freedom to change thinks in the future.So i create a a view Model

```
public class ViewModelContactCompany
{
     public String Name { get; set; }
     List<Contact> contacts { get; set; }
    //etc just a sample
}
```

Controller

```
public class Controler
{
//param id is a id from company
//to do a relationship
public Action ControlerDetailsContact(int? id)
{
    ViewModelContactCompany x = new ViewModelContactCompany();
    //Do a linq, sqlquery,etc

    x.Name = "sample"; //get name of company by id;

    for (;;)
    {
        //where id = contact.CompanyID
        //add a new object typeof contact to the viewmodel
        //with the data get from the relationship
        x.contacts.Add(new Contact());
    }

    //and in the final return object viewmodel  to the view 
    return View(x);
 }
```

}

Now the View

```
@model /patch.ViewModelContactCompany

and here you get the data on the object return on the controler
```

[What is ViewModel in MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11064316/what-is-viewmodel-in-mvc)